# Seeking conditional formatting formula based on date and another cell's value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Example:

[image: example]

- if status is 'closed' then due due date is [green]
- if status is 'major' or 'minor' and overdue based on TODAY, then due date is [red]
- if not overdue or 'closed', due date format is [clear]

Comment: This should be the most basic example of conditional formatting. Just google "Excel conditional formatting" and check the first 5 links.

Comment: The most basic type of conditional formatting is conditional formatting of a cell based on its own value.  I did not find a canonical question duplicating this one.

Comment: @Vityata that is not true.. please refer to Degan's response

Comment: @pnuts - so you are trying to tell me that the question is ok as per the rules here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask? Without any minimal efforts shown? I guess my version of the link is different.

Comment: @Vityata you are 100% wrong given that the answer is not found in your simple (without effort or verification) google instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create two rules:

> Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Green: `= A1 = "Closed"`
Red: `= AND(OR(A1="major", A1="minor"),B1<NOW())`

Apply desired format.

---

Your rules should look like below once complete. To get to this screen to check:

> Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need two conditional formatting. (Apply to `B:B`)

For Green:

```
=IF(A2="Closed",TRUE,FALSE)
```

For Red:

```
=IF(AND(OR(A2="Minor",A2="Major"),B2<TODAY(),B2<>""),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: No worries, my first downvote, but I will get over it.